# Rails routing sometimes replaces the id in url with id-name. How do I avoid problems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Generally the url from my report page looks like this:

```
 http://test-account.peter:3000/offices/7/reports/index
```

However, sometimes it looks like this:

```
 http://test-account.peter:3000/offices/7-peters-office/reports/index
```

Why does this happen?

It was not really a problem until we changed the controller action from a GET to a POST and renamed it. We had to do this so we could pack more parameters in to the ajax request. Users still have this section of the site bookmarked and it throws errors all day long.

I have tried to redirect the route:

```
   get '/offices/*all/reports/index' => 'offices#show'
   get '/offices/:office_id/reports/index' => 'offices#show'
   get '/offices/:office_name/reports/index' => 'offices#show'
```

Is there a way to catch the name? Or do I have to prevent the name from being added to the url in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

In the controller, you would be able to parse the parameter to get just the first character and check if its an integer. However, it would be much better to debug how the parameter is getting assigned to different values and ensure only the id is used. If you're linking to that route in a view, check what is being passed in the link and confirm the value is what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Rails does routing it does not  look in your database for matched data. So without looking at data, your three routes are exactly the same, the variable (office_id & office_name) is just named different. If you get a request on example /offices/:office_name/reports/index, rails will just match the first one since both routes match the request.

You need something in the path that indicates its a name or id. If you will really never have a name and id with the same search, then you could just have one route and try to match a id or name from the DB in the controller.